# android getText().toString().equals("0") doesn't work

Tags: android

My code:

```
if (edittext1.getText().toString().equals("0"))
   edittext1.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(1)});
```

In .xml file I set `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` I want, if user writes in the beginning of edittext1 "0", than he can't write nothing more.

It doesn't work, how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that edittext1.getText() not returning null?

Comment: @Aubin If it was, then the OP would get a NPE.  Ross, what does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Did you try to Log a message inside the if block ? Maybe your expression in the if statement is correct, but the setFilters are not firing. Maybe. Just a thought.

Comment: @Simon "it doesn't work" means, I can write "00", "01" etc. I want to block it. I want to allow input numbers like "201", "30", "0", not "00", "01". Swayam, I didn't try it, cause i don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you make this check everytime the input has changed, not only once:

```
    edittext1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
               if (edittext1.getText().toString().equals("0")){
                    edittext1.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(1)});
                }else{
                    edittext1.setFilters(new InputFilter[0]); // remove filter
                }
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    });
```

Comment: I fixed the code above, please have a new try. I tried it in the emulator and it worked pretty well.